# How to get all the values of dropdownlist in var using jquery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I want to compare string with all the values from dropdownlist. And which value of dropdownlist is matched with that string and that should be selected.

example

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
     <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListVendor" class="form-control text-box-border" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="vendor_name" DataValueField="vendor_name"></asp:DropDownList>
     <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:Nibrass_DBConnectionString %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [vendor_name] FROM [Vendor_tb]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</div>
```

DropDownListVendor have return and show two values in drop down list [Compaq,Hp].

now i want to compare one string with that dropdownlistvendor value of all.
I tried this code for getting all the values of dropdownlist. But it doesn't work.

```
var vendorArr = [];
$('#DropDownListVendor').each(function() {
  vendorArr.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
alert("vendor Array ==" + vendorArr[0]);
```

it returns in alert `vendor Array == Undefined`.
thanks.

Comment: ` $('#DropDownListVendor').each(function () ` you select by ID here, but expect multiple elements to be selected, this can't work at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through options inside the select list using [`.map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/) like

```
var vendorArr = $("#DropDownListVendor option").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

Since, asp dropdownlist id might change when rendered in html in case you are using asp master page you can use [`Attribute Ends With Selector`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) to resolve that like:

```
var vendorArr = $("[id$='DropDownListVendor'] option").map(function() {
  return this.value;
}).get();
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to loop the `options` in your case. The `#DropDownListVendor` selector will only get you the `select` element itself, and the currently `selected value`, not all possible values.

```
$('#DropDownListVendor option').each(function() {
    vendorArr.push($(this).attr('value'));
});
```

Working example:

```js
var vendorArr = [];

$('#DropDownListVendor option').each(function() {
    vendorArr.push($(this).attr('value'));
});

console.log(vendorArr);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<select id="DropDownListVendor">
  <option value="Compaq">Compaq</option>
  <option value="HP">HP</option>
  <option value="Lenovo">Lenovo</option>
  <option value="IBM">IBM</option>
</select>
```